# How to convert GMT to PST and PDT time in oracle

Tags: oracle

GMT to PST conversion  and GMT to DST conversion

Comment: Please edit the question and show an example of what you are talking about.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Is there a question here?  So far you simply have a statement. And that statement is not true.  When (and even "IF") Standard Time and DST start depends on where you live.  And as @mathguy said, there is nowhere in the world that they start on a Friday.

Comment: @EdStevens - there are a few places where DST starts on a Friday - just not on the first Friday in May. This year (2021) DST starts Friday, March 26 in Israel, Jordan and Syria. It will end on a Sunday in Israel, and on a Friday in Jordan and Syria.

Comment: Also, both to you and to @WernfriedDomscheit - the OP's question is displayed in plain view, in the title of his post: *HOW to convert ......* The only problem I had with his question is the made-up DST rules.

Answer (score 0):

Did you make up your own time zone region? There is no place in the world where daylight saving is from the first Friday in March till the first Monday in November.

Other than that the question is trivial - use the `at time zone` operator, like below. Note that I use a timestamp literal for the input, but you could use any expression that evaluates to a timestamp in the 'GMT' time zone (or in any time zone for that matter). Note that `'America/Los_Angeles'` follows the PST/PDT model, but not with the dates you indicated in your question.

```
select timestamp '2020-10-29 01:30:00.000 GMT' 
       at time zone 'America/Los_Angeles' as pst_pdt_time
from   dual;

PST_PDT_TIME                               
-----------------------------------------------
2020-10-28 18:30:00.000 America/Los_Angeles PDT
```

Answer (score 0):

Time zone PST and/or PDT are ambiguous, see

```
SELECT tzname, tzabbrev, TZ_OFFSET(tzname)
FROM V$TIMEZONE_NAMES 
WHERE tzabbrev IN ('PST','PDT')
    OR tzname IN ('PST','PDT');
```

| TZNAME | TZABBREV | TZ_OFFSET(TZNAME) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| America/Bahia_Banderas | PST | -06:00 |
| America/Boise | PST | -07:00 |
| America/Boise | PDT | -07:00 |
| America/Creston | PST | -07:00 |
| America/Dawson | PST | -08:00 |
| America/Dawson | PDT | -08:00 |
| America/Dawson_Creek | PST | -07:00 |
| America/Dawson_Creek | PDT | -07:00 |
| America/Ensenada | PST | -08:00 |
| America/Ensenada | PDT | -08:00 |
| America/Hermosillo | PST | -07:00 |
| America/Inuvik | PST | -07:00 |
| America/Juneau | PST | -09:00 |
| America/Juneau | PDT | -09:00 |
| America/Los_Angeles | PST | -08:00 |
| America/Los_Angeles | PDT | -08:00 |
| America/Mazatlan | PST | -07:00 |
| America/Metlakatla | PST | -08:00 |
| America/Metlakatla | PDT | -08:00 |
| America/Santa_Isabel | PST | -08:00 |
| America/Santa_Isabel | PDT | -08:00 |
| America/Sitka | PST | -09:00 |
| America/Sitka | PDT | -09:00 |
| America/Tijuana | PST | -08:00 |
| America/Tijuana | PDT | -08:00 |
| America/Vancouver | PST | -08:00 |
| America/Vancouver | PDT | -08:00 |
| America/Whitehorse | PST | -08:00 |
| America/Whitehorse | PDT | -08:00 |
| Canada/Pacific | PST | -08:00 |
| Canada/Pacific | PDT | -08:00 |
| Canada/Yukon | PST | -08:00 |
| Canada/Yukon | PDT | -08:00 |
| Mexico/BajaNorte | PST | -08:00 |
| Mexico/BajaNorte | PDT | -08:00 |
| Mexico/BajaSur | PST | -07:00 |
| Pacific/Pitcairn | PST | -08:00 |
| PST | LMT | -08:00 |
| PST | PST | -08:00 |
| PST | PDT | -08:00 |
| PST | PWT | -08:00 |
| PST | PPT | -08:00 |
| PST8PDT | PDT | -08:00 |
| PST8PDT | PST | -08:00 |
| US/Pacific | PST | -08:00 |
| US/Pacific | PDT | -08:00 |
| US/Pacific-New | PST | -08:00 |
| US/Pacific-New | PDT | -08:00 |

Use timezone region name as shown by @mathguy. These region names also apply correct rule for DST changes.